# How do I use ui.bootstrap in a MeanJS controller?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meanjs

Every time I try to use any of the bootstrap functions from ui.bootstrap, I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ui.bootstrapProvider <- ui.bootstrap <- CollapseController...
```

I've tried many various ways to fix this problem but I'm stuck at this point. Right now I'm just trying to make a toggle switch on a comments view. Here's my controller:

```
angular.module('remarks').controller('CollapseController', ['$scope', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate',
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
  }
]);
```

That's an additional controller to the default one (RemarksController) and I've registered the remarks module as such:

```
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('remarks', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Finally, here's the view that is trying to make use of this controller:

```
<section ng-controller="RemarksController" ng-init="find()">
  <div><h6>Remarks</h6></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="post-remarks">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="media"  ng-controller="CollapseController">
        <div class="media-heading">
          <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" type="button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" ng-if="(!isCollapsed)"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-if="isCollapsed"></span> 
          </button> 
        </div>

        <div class="panel-collapse collapse in" uib-collapse="isCollapsed">
          (content)
        </div>
```

Please understand, I can figure out ways around this to do this one operation differently. But, I don't want to. I want to be able to use the ui-bootstrap functionality so I'm trying to get to the root of the problem here.

How can I get the ui.bootstrap dependency to inject so I can use it in this controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ui.bootstrap is by default added by MEAN 4.X. No need to register it in the controller.

https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/core/client/app/config.js

I don't see the problem with your code..
http://jsfiddle.net/zdyv90w1/1/

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('CollapseController', function($scope) {
  $scope.isCollapse = false;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However I haven't "checked" it because the problem is still not solved. I am no longer getting any javascript errors, but at the same time, the ui.bootstrap functionality is not working. I click the toggle button, nothing toggles, and the value remains false. This also happens in your fiddle. Any thoughts?

Comment: OK, nevermind, I must have been using an old version of the documentation. I was using the attribute "uib-collapse" rather than just "collapse". It is working now.

Comment: Actually, I was using the current documentation, but MEANJS is using an old version of ui-bootsrap. For some reason the new version uses "uib" in front of things.

Comment: @tutley had your same issue and using angular-bootstrap v0.13.4 docu resolved my issue. was this your same version?